# Differential equation $y y'' - (y')^3=0$ - $\frac{dy}{dt}= \frac{1}{\ln|y|+c}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to solve the differential equation $y y'' - (y')^3=0$.

I thought I could use the change of variable $v(y)=y'(t)$ and $v'(y)=v \frac{dv}{dy}$ where I got $v= \frac{1}{\ln|y|+c}$ and then $\frac{dy}{dt}= \frac{1}{\ln|y|+c}$ $\iff (\ln|y|+c)dy=-dt$. I think it is very hard to solve this last differential equation.

The teacher mention that $(\ln|y|+c)dy=-dt$ is $y \ln|y|+(c-1)y=-t+k$, but I didn't see why, and the good answer according to the book is $y \ln|y|-y+c_1y +t= c_2$

Is there exist another simple way to solve this problem? Or could I still use the last differential equation?

Comment: You realize that $y \ln|y|+(c-1)y=-t+k$ and $y \ln|y|-y+c_1y +t= c_2$ are strictly equivalent, don't you?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be not knowing the fact that, integrating by parts,
$$
\int \ln y\,dy=\int 1\ln y\,dy=y\ln y-\int y/y\,dy=y\ln y-y+C.
$$

Answer (score 1):

The problem can strongly simplify using $$\dfrac{d^2x}{dy^2}=-\frac{\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}}{\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)^3}$$ Replacing, and assuming $\dfrac{dy}{dx}\neq 0$ (remember that $y=C$ is a trivial solution) the differential equation becomes $$y\dfrac{d^2x}{dy^2}+1=0$$ which integrate quite simply to get $$x=c_1+c_2 y-y \log (y)$$

Now, if you want $y$ as a function of $x$, once more we should find Lambert function $$y=\frac{c_1-x}{W\left(c_3 (c_1-x)\right)}$$